# Is there any point in assigning all values to a struct?

Tags: c++, c, memory

I was experimenting with `SendInput` recently and discovered that everything worked as expected without assigning other values to the structure

```
#include <Windows.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    INPUT input;

    input.type = 1;
    input.ki.wVk = 0x41;

    SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(INPUT));

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

If you take a look at the MSDN definition of the `INPUT` structure that I am using, it has many additional variables (except for `type` and `wVk` which are the only ones I set).

Is there any point in adding on something similar to `input.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;` for all of the other fields in that structure? I assumed that, by default, when you allocate the structure it will write zeros to the memory so there is no point in setting these variables?

Comment: "I assumed that, by default, when you allocate the structure it will write zeros to the memory" - bad assumption, doesn't hold.

Comment: `INPUT input;` http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization

Comment: To be a bit more explicit: The effective way to do this is `INPUT input = {0}` which will in fact zero every member. You don't need to know all the names of all the members, that's the good thing.

Comment: Please don't be smarter then guys that create Windows and use this simple macro `ZeroMemory(&input,sizeof(INPUT));` as they do ;)

Comment: Given the code, and taking @MSalters's hint one step farther, you could replace `INPUT input; input.type = 1;` with `INPUT input = { INPUT_KEYBOARD };` which will *both* set the required `type` (to `1` but avoiding magic constants) *and* zero out the rest of the members.

Comment: @Logman. Please forget `ZeroMemory`. There are safer and more expressive ways to zero initialize a struct.

Comment: @sbabbi for bare initialization I agree but for reinitialization I don't see safer and faster way.

Comment: @Logman: `input = INPUT{ };`.

Comment: @MSalters only for c++11. To be honest my comment was a little bit humoristic but saying `memset` is dangerous is like saying kitchen knife is dangerous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Local variables (and by extension members of a local struct variable) are uninitialized, so attempting to read or write them results in undefined behavior.

It happens to work in this case, but you can't depend on that.

That being said, the fields of this struct were probably all 0 because it is local to the `main` function, the memory for the process was likely cleared before it was started, and the variable doesn't go out of scope for the life of the program so the space it uses on the stack isn't used by anything else.

But again, that is an implementation detail which can't be depended on.  So better to explicitly initialize all values.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to assign variables, but I think it is better practice to instantiate to `0` or `null`, and have check point along the way when you `get` these variables. It makes your code more robust in my opinion, because you are never protected from forgetting what was instantiated and what wasn't.

Additionally, no, by default if a value is not instantiated, then it not written in memory.

Comment: What do you mean by instantiated. He instantiate `input` on stack when he declare it. He doesn't initialize it but it's not same as instantiate. He can use his variable without any risk to application integrity.